# Remove duplicate rows based on columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Hi have a dataset with 2 rows :

data :

```
user_id,city
123,delhi
456,Pune
123,Goa
789,Hyderabad
```

when i check the duplicated user_id, i get only 1 row:
Code :

```
df2[df2["user_id"].duplicated()]["user_id"]
```

Output :

```
1 123
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

When i try to check the duplicate based on user_id :

```
df2[df2["user_id"].duplicated()]
```

I get only 1 record in output :

```
1 123 Delhi
```

There is no junk character or space in user_id column

How to find all duplicated user_id and delete one of them ?

I tried to delete from row index position but didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

please try using

`df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id'], keep='first')`

You can use `keep='first'` or `keep='last'`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it didn't worked for me.
I tried - 
df2[df2["user_id"]==123];
df2.drop([1],inplace = True)

Not a good approach. but i'm ok as i have only few duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
nodup = df2[~df2["user_id"].duplicated()]
```